# JUnit: Is there a RunListener method, which is called after @After annotated method?

Tags: testing, junit, listener, testng

Is there a way to invoke a method after all @After annotated methods of a test method had been run?
I need this for a special framework for my company.
In testng i can use the afterInvocation method, which is called after every configuration method. Is there some alternative in JUnit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rule will run after all the `@After`s. The [ExternalResource](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.html) could be abused in order to do what you want:

```
public class VerifyTest {
    @Rule public ExternalResource externalResource = new ExternalResource() {
        public void after() {
            System.out.println("ExternalResource.after");
        }
    };

    @After
    public void after1() {
        System.out.println("after1");
    }

    @After
    public void after2() {
        System.out.println("after2");
    }

   @Test
   public void testVerify throws IOException {
   }
}
```

Comment: thx, i didn't know about rules until this time. But i found out that the method testFinished from RunListener is also called after all @After methods.